# Using git stash, checkout previous commit, and going back

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-stash

I wanted to go back to a commit to see how things were at that moment, so I did

```
git stash
```

... to save my changes then I used

```
git checkout <hash>
```

When done with my exploration, I just wanted to go back where I was and I used

```
git stash apply
```

Now files are messed up and I can't see further commits when using `git log`

What's going on? How do I get back to where I was?

**EDIT**

Tried to do a `git checkout master` but had some conflicts (a `README.md`, marking "deleted by US")

So I added it, stashed my changes, used `git checkout master` and then applied the stash.

Fixed the `README.md` conflict and everythings's fine.

GIT hurts my brain.

Comment: The stash is for changes, not full content.  `git checkout @{-1}; git stash apply` should do it if I recall correctly.  `@{-1}` is "the branch I just had checked out", you could just specify its name directly.

Comment: By 'full content' you mean staged changes? I had nothing on stage when I did `git stash`. The problem was applying stash while I had a previous commit checked out, right? I guess so because I repeated that process but used `git checkout master` to go back before `git stash apply` and it worked as I expected

Comment: That's pretty much it: `git stash apply` (or pop if you're done with the stash) merges the stashed changes. All that happened was your stashed work didn't apply cleanly to the other commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to undo the mess you made with `git stash apply`. You can do this with `git reset --hard HEAD`. (Warning: this will throw away all local changes.) Then you need to check out your previous branch. If you have not done any other `git checkout` commands, you can use `git checkout @{-1}` to checkout the previous branch. Finally, you can `git stash apply` to reapply your stash exactly where you were working before all this started.

Comment: Hmm.. didn't know about the `@{-1}` part, what that means exactly? Could I use `git checkout master` instead?

Comment: @zok It refers to the branch which you previously had checked out. As you seem to have already figured out you can also provide the branch name explicitly.

Comment: With modern git you can also use `git checkout -`, which works similarly to `cd -`.

Comment: @Ruslan You should post that as ananswer.

Comment: OK ... working in eclipse ...  So I did the git reset --hard HEAD but then when I do a git stash apply I get an error:  "Applying stashed commit '16117a3' failed due to 'Applying stashed changes resulted in a conflict'" which is not really helpful and seems my stash, while I can see it, I can't get to it.